# WordPress jQuery Conflicts

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am running scripting I turned into a WordPress Plugin. It works outside of WordPress as a standalone application and it works locally as a WordPress Plugin.

I now am trying it out the live web site and it isn't working. It doesn't make any sense why I am getting jQuery errors - especially when I have a duplicate of what is on the live server on my test server, and one works while the other doesn't.

Any suggestions is would help.

http://mapleleafshotstove.com/2013/05/17/lazy-long-weekend-friday-links/ - the plugin is the commenting system.

Lines 791 to 897 is where I have the scripting that has issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var alerts = 0, total = 192;
 jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  ...
 });
</script>
```

It looks like the error I am getting is jQuery(...).metadata is is not a function. Which means it doesn't like the http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata plugin I am using.

Comment: Can you reduce the problem to a small reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, I posted as an edit above. It looks like the metadata plugin is not well liked. `jQuery('.options ul li.reply', body).metadata().id;`

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is running in noConflict mode by default, so don't call `noConflict()` again, just use a proper DOM ready function that keeps the value of the dollarsign as `jQuery` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var alerts = 0, total = 192;
 jQuery(function($) {
      // do what you normally do
      var id = $('.options ul li.reply').metadata().prop('id');
 });
</script>
```

and add scripts in your plugin with :

```
wp_register_script( 'myscript', plugins_url('/js/myscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript' );
```

Comment: Be there and done that. In the first installment and it didn't work. I than tried the `noConflict()` - why does this work on one server and another. Is what I am finding odd.

Comment: Well, on the posted page my console lights up like a christmas tree, so it's hard to say which one of all the errors you should check first ?

Comment: I have another method of getting the data - I will just avoid the metadata plugin altogether. I noticed all the other errors as well, there been before I installed this, thanks for your help!